# firebase storage: export 'storage' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app'

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When import firebase storage i got error:
`firebase storage: export 'storage' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app'`

My app code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import  "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = firebase.storage();

export { storage, firebase as default };
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the CDN since I find it reliable
compared to node.js I dont know much of what's going on with it but it hasnt worked for me not even once but I believe it works for others especially when using a framework like VUE.js/ Angular etc

I'm just on plain HTML & JS so I believe it would still work for you as well

but here is the solution you are looking for

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.2/firebase-app.js";

import { getStorage, ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.2/firebase-storage.js";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);
const storageRef = ref(storage);
```

Reactjs has very similar properties to just JavaScript and it utilizes node the same way with just a few minor tweaks to your configuration