# firebase storage: export 'storage' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app' Continuation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I've been following firebase storage tutorial trying to setup my website for some storage and I only got as far as my response from the previous question asked by Fiodorov Andrei on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70509884/firebase-storage-export-storage-imported-as-firebase-was-not-found-in-fi) to resolve his issue

my question is based from the firebase storage YouTube tutorial which I followed till the 4th min 41sec [Video here](https://youtu.be/-IFRVMEhZDc?t=281) where she uploaded a non existing file which she created from thin air and basically uploaded it to the cloud storage

but I recieved an uncaught ref error like so => [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZJVp.png) and I am not so sure how to fix it

the intention is to make an HTML file where a user can upload or download their own files after being logged in (that explains the hidden email in my heartbeat.js)

So from initialising the cloud storage what is next? or what can I fix?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the video demonstration, they are glossing over the imports for each of those functions, instead encouraging you to review the [written documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) that accompanies that video.

The below snippets have been copied from the documentation at `https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files`. At the time of copying, these snippets are copyrighted by Google Inc and licensed under the [Apache 2.0 License](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) and have been included here for completeness.

### Upload from a Blob or File

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');

// 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

### Upload from a Byte Array

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');

const bytes = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21]); // 'Hello, world!' in ASCII
uploadBytes(storageRef, bytes).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded an array!');
});
```

### Upload from a String

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadString } from "firebase/storage";
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');

// Raw string is the default if no format is provided
const message = 'This is my message.';
uploadString(storageRef, message).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a raw string!');
});

// Base64 formatted string
const message2 = '5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
uploadString(storageRef, message2, 'base64').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
});

// Base64url formatted string
const message3 = '5b6p5Y-344GX44G-44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
uploadString(storageRef, message3, 'base64url').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64url string!');
});

// Data URL string
const message4 = 'data:text/plain;base64,5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
uploadString(storageRef, message4, 'data_url').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
});
```